# Delaying an -(id)init instance; is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, nsurl

I've been trying to get a PDF from an NSURL that is changed during a

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The change in NSURL logs perfectly, but the view is loaded before the app has a chance to act upon that change.  Is there a way to delay the reading of the change in URL by simply moving the code to the

```
viewDidLoad
```

section, or do I have to drastically change everything?  Here's my -(id)init method:

```
- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    CFURLRef pdfURL = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:appDelegate.baseURL ofType:@"pdf"]];
    pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
}
return self;
```

}

Comment: If you need to change your question, just edit it:) It's helpful if you leave a comment to the person who wrote the answer you received to let them know. If you found that you have a whole different problem to solve, just ask a new question. You can cite this in the new question and indicate how it's different.

Comment: I've marked this questions for deletion by the admins.  Thanks anyways though Tim, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Yes, I know .. I'm the moderator that received your flag. (the ♦ next to a user's name indicates that user is a moderator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to work with network the proven approach is to use asynchronous calls. This is because of the nature of a network connection; it is unpredictable, not always reliable, the time you need to spend to get the result from the server can vary from millisecond to minutes.

I would make a data model class, MyPDFModel, with an asynchronous method, that should run a thread to get the file from the server:

```
- (void)requestPDFWithURL:(NSURL*)fileURL
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(requestPDFWithURLThreaded:) toTarget:self fileURL];
}

- (void)requestPDFWithURLThreaded:(NSURL*)fileURL
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    // do whatever you need to get either the file or an error
    if (isTheFileValid)
        [_delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(requestDidGetPDF:) withObject:PDFFile waitUntilDone:NO];
    else
        [_delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:) withObject:error waitUntilDone:NO];

    [pool release];
}
```

Meanwhile the UI should display an activity indicator.

The MyPDFModelDelegate protocol should have two methods:

```
- (void)requestDidGetPDF:(YourPDFWrapperClass*)PDFDocument;
- (void)requestDidFailWithError:(NSError*)error;
```

`YourPDFWrapperClass` is used to return an autoreleased document.

The delegate can let the UI know that the data has been updated, for example by posting a notification if the delegate is a part of the data model.

This is just an example, the implementation can be different depending on your needs, but I think you will get the idea.

P.S. Delaying an init is a very bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the post... But I'm not using a server, nor do I ever hope to at my novice-like level.  All resources are local, so my problem is initialization timing.

Comment: You are welcome. It does not really matter if the file is on the server of stored locally. If you have issues with timing the asynchronous approach is applicable regardless of the reason of the delay.

Comment: Davyd, you are a lifesaver!  Be on the lookout for this thing, it'll be my first app!