# NSString Value Changed AFTER -(id)init

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsstring

OK, so I've been told it's a terrible idea to delay the

```
-(id)init
```

part of my code, but unfortunately it is NSLogging a NULL value before the string has time to register a change.

Here's my code for the id init

```
- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    CFStringRef aCFString = (CFStringRef)[appDelegate baseURL];
    CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), aCFString, NULL, NULL); 
    pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
    NSLog(@"xSheetMusicViewController - %@",appDelegate.baseURL);
    CFRelease(pdfURL);
}
return self;
```

}

and here's the Console Output:

```
2011-09-18 09:52:22.275 SheetMuse[57499:b603] value - (null)
failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.
2011-09-18 09:52:24.575 SheetMuse[57499:b603] xSheetMusicViewController - (null)
2011-09-18 09:52:24.581 SheetMuse[57499:b603] Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x4e5a910>.
2011-09-18 09:52:24.624 SheetMuse[57499:b603] value - mussette.pdf
2011-09-18 09:52:24.627 SheetMuse[57499:b603] Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x4cc1ba0>.
2011-09-18 09:52:24.628 SheetMuse[57499:b603] value - mussette.pdf
```

The original NULL value was from app launch, when it should be null (after all, why would I need the string at launch?) but then it mentions that it "failed to find the PDF header" which is quite new to me.  then xSheetMusicViewController tries to grab the string value, but it's still null from launch.  Then the value is updated from a

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

method which means that somehow I either have to delay the -(id)init method or find a faster way to update the value of the string before the init.

Can anyone help?

Comment: why asking the same question again? There exist a suitable answer for your problem in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459339/delaying-an-idinit-instance-is-it-possible

Comment: It isn't suitable.  Sir Davyd thought I was using a server.  And while I would love to just insert an asynchronous dispatch and make it right as rain, I can't.  All files are local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your setup code out of init and into a separate method that can be called later.

Comment: Brilliant, but which method?  I've tried calling it in the -awakeFrom Nib method, which only served up a nasty EXC_BAD_ACCESS, (partially due to the fact that I don't have a nib...) and then I put it in the viewDidLoad which only brought up 16 errors about how the object was undeclared.  Should I make a private method to initialize, or is there an API for this?

Comment: Where is this class being instantiated?  Can you load the pfd there and then call a setup method on the class?  Or load the pfd and then instantiate the class either passing in the pfd in the init method or after init vis a property?

Comment: My app flow works a lot like this MainView (tableView)->SheetMusicView (with pdf).  I can't load the PDF in the main view, because all of the heavy lifting is being done with the Leaves project renderers, and only SheetMusicView is importing and parsing the PDF.